# Domination of the Lebesgue measure by the normal law

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, normal-distribution, lebesgue-measure

I encountered a problem in measure theory recently which asked that  for  any set $A \in B_{\mathbb{R}}$, if $\Phi(A)=0$ does that imply that $\lambda(A)=0$, where $\Phi$ is the standard normal law and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $(\mathbb{R},B_{\mathbb{R}})$.

I found that all countably infinite sets $A$ have $\Phi(A)=0$ and also $\lambda(A)=0$. But is there a way to prove this or is there a counter example lurking somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Well $\Phi$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$:
$$ \Phi(dx) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} \,\lambda(dx).$$
Since the density is positive, we can invert this
$$\lambda(dx) = \sqrt{2\pi} e^{x^2/2}\, \Phi(dx),$$
which implies that $\lambda \ll \Phi$.